# Should the word after "e.g." be capital

Tags: grammar, punctuation

If you are using a word that normally wouldn't start with a capital letter, should it be lower case after an *e.g.*? Also should *e.g.* have a capital *E* at the start of a sentence?

Example phrases:

> - Should I always plug in electrical items? e.g. Electric hairdryer, phone charger...
> - Should I always plug in electrical items? e.g. electric hairdryer, phone charger...
> - Should I always plug in electrical items? E.g. Electric hairdryer, phone charger...
> - Should I always plug in electrical items? E.g. electric hairdryer, phone charger...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to capitalise the word after "e.g." because it's an acronym; it's short for *exempli gratia*, basically Latin for "for example". The full stop doesn't make it the end of a sentence. The confusion might arise from the fact that unlike other acronyms the letters are not usually capitalised. I believe that this is because the acronym has been around long enough that it is treated a bit like it's a word itself.

As far as capitalising at the start of a sentence: I might if I ever were to use it, but I can't think of a case where I ever would. Remember that it stands for "for example". Starting a sentence with "for example" seems fairly nonsensical, as it's a conjunctive adverb.

> "Should I always plug in electrical items? e.g. Electric hairdryer,
>   phone charger.."

is much better written:

> "Should I always plug in electrical items, e.g. electric hairdryer,
>   phone charger?"

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with starting a sentence with a conjunctive adverb. For example, this sentence starts with one. Certainly this one does, too. Besides, some conjunctive adverbs almost _require_ being at the start of a sentence. Anyway, I agree with your main point here: _e.g._ (which means ‘for example’, but is not appropriate in all cases where ‘for example’ may be used) is odd sentence-initially, even if _for example_ itself is not necessarily.

Comment: "There’s nothing wrong with starting a sentence with a conjunctive adverb. For example, this sentence starts with one." To my mind, that's crying out for a semicolon before "for example"; i.e. "...conjunctive adverb; for example..."

Comment: @Grey Area But maybe only to some people. And that doesn't include everyone. For example, it doesn't include me.

Comment: Note that "e.g." will usually have a comma _after_ it as well. See GG's table of style guide recommendations:  http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ie-versus-eg?page=2